# How to return in Angular 8 with Observable and pipe()?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I use my own data service in Angular with a `save()` method witch can run create or update on server side. But before send datas to server it's need to be check datas are valid or not.

If data isn't valid, the communication to the server will not happen.

Here is the code:

```js
  save(data: T): Observable<boolean> {
    const preparedData = JSON.stringify(data.prepareToSave());

    if (!data.isValid) {
      // if data is invalid we should return before send datas to server
      return new Observable<T>().pipe(map(() => false));
    }

    if (!data.id) {
      // create
      return this.http.post(this.url, preparedData, this.options)
        .pipe(map(() => true));
    } else {
      // update
      return this.http.put(this.url + '/' + data.id, preparedData, this.options)
        .pipe(map(() => true));
    }
  }
```

Now if the `data` isn't valid I need to return an `Observable<boolean>` with `false`.

In the component I have this code:

```js
  saveDatas() {
    this.dataService.save(this.customer).subscribe( (resolve: boolean) => {
      if (resolve) {
        // save OK
      } else {
        // save failed (1)
      }
    }, (error: any) => {
      // save failed (2)
    });
  }
```

If the save fails because of `this.customer.isValid` is `false` then I expect `subscribe` will get `false` from dataService. Exactly from this line:

```js
    if (!data.isValid) {
      // if data is invalid we should return before send datas to server
      return new Observable<T>().pipe(map(() => false));
    }
```

But something goes wrong, and I can't figure out what's the mistake.

Why don't return the data service with `false`?

Comment: `But something goes wrong` ← What does that mean? What is wrong? Is the value not `falsy` or is the observable not being created? Also you should import `of` from `rxjs` and return an observable using `return of(false);`

Comment: @Igor: the wrong is: the component get's nothing back. The `subscribe()` does not detect something is returned. And I don't understand why.

Comment: Attach your debugger and step through the method. Is it entered? Does it throw an exception? Where does it exit?

Comment: @netdjw - Did you try `return of(false)`, as suggested by @Igor?

Comment: @Igor: the `return of(false);` solved the problem, thank you! @ConnorsFan thank you too!

Answer (score 2):

Typically you would address the failure case for invalid data with a thrown error

```
if (!data.isValid) {
  // if data is invalid we should return before send datas to server
  return throwError(new Error('Invalid request'));
}
```

Then your error condition can catch it and present the error to the user in a way that makes sense

That said your form should be the first line of defense here, it should never even make it to your service if the form is not valid.  I would take the time to look into reactive form validation